# I don't know how to use elastic_client Query.range

Tags: flutter, dart, elasticsearch

#### problem

I am currently developing a Flutter application. The language we are using is dart.
I am thinking of using elastic search data, and I would like to use a package called elastic_client to retrieve the data.
I am trying to retrieve data by specifying a time, but I don't know how to use it.
I would appreciate it if you could help me.

#### What we want to achieve

I want to retrieve data by time in the elastic_client package.
If I write it in curl, it will be as follows.

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
                "gte" : "2022-08-16T16:18:00+09:00", "lte": "now", "format" : "date_time_no_millis"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I want to do this with elastic_client.
I think I can do it with Query.range in the search method, but I don't know how to use it.

#### code

I want to get data with _call_elastic.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  _call_elastic() async {
    dynamic a = "a";
    final transport = HttpTransport(url: 'url');
    final client = Client(transport);
    final search1 = await client.search(
        index: '',
        type:'_doc',
        query: Query.range(gte: 'a'),
        );
    var map = search1.toMap();
    print(map);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _call_elastic,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### What we tried

I've looked at the elastic_client documentation and fiddled with it, but I can't figure out how to use it.
The elastic_client sample code doesn't show how to use Query.range.
[elastic_client](https://pub.dev/packages/elastic_client)
[elastic_client samplecode](https://github.com/isoos/elastic_client/blob/master/example/example.dart)
[Query.range](https://pub.dev/documentation/elastic_client/latest/elastic_client/Query/range.html)

#### Lastly.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Also, if there is any other way to get data from elastic_search in flutter by specifying the time, I would appreciate it if you could tell me about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just try something like:

```dart
await client.search(
      index: 'my_index',
      type: 'my_type',
      query: Query.range(
          '@timestamp',
          gte: "2022-08-16T16:18:00+09:00",
          lte: "now"),
      source: true);
```

But the client does not take in charge the `format`.

Maybe Pr are welcome ?